# ObjectMapper no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1993-08-25'), problem with XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-deserialization, objectmapper, xmlmapper

I am using jaxb2-maven-plugin xjc to generate java classes from xsd schema (example here: https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb ). Which works.

Secondly I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper to deserialize XML file to Java object, but during deserialzation i got following error(i tried to delete this attribute and all other attributes were OK):

> **ObjectMapper no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1993-08-25')**

Problem is with this generated java attribute:

```
 @XmlElement(name = "Created", required = true)
 @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
 protected XMLGregorianCalendar created;
```

In XML:

```
<ns2:Created>1993-08-25</ns2:Created>
```

I tried to set date format to xml mapper
`xmlMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));`,
but it didnt work.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did anyone ever find a solution?